# How to write smaller applications in android?

Tags: android, diskspace

I wrote very simple application in Android Eclipse Plugin that does almost nothing. Installed it takes 1MB of disk space (that's what I see in informations about it).

Is there any way to make it take less disk space ?

Comment: It is about your resources file. In brief, if you have many .png files, it takes much space.

Answer (score 3):

**there are multiple things you could do to decrease the size of you apps.**

- Can you move images to the web and async them into your app?
- Make sure your files are completely compressed as much as possible. Use pngquant or tinypng.
- Check for any repetition in the images. You might be able to use 9-patch for it.
- Allow users to move data to an SD card.

You might even be able to make your own drawables for certain images.

If the size of app is less that 2 MB then there are less chances that user will uninstall the app, 
atleast thats what people say there is no real evidence of that.

if this ins't enough for you, you should take a look at **[ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)**

The **ProGuard** tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized app

In the end is all about if your app is helpfull to the user. then they probably wil not delete it because of it's size.